# Saving Passing Parameter Values in JMeter

Tags: parameters, save, jmeter, beanshell

I have few variable in my jmeter script such as $Z{name}, ${DOBZ}, ${SSN} and so on and during the test run I like to save these passed values into a file either txt or csv. Any ideas how to do it or is there are any beanshell code available which I can use to save parameter or any dynamic regular exp values from my script.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure JMeter so it will automatically save variables into .jtl file using `sample_variables` property.

From the documentation:

> Optional list of JMeter variable names whose values are to be saved in the result data files.
>   Use commas to separate the names. For example:
>
> **sample_variables=SESSION_ID,REFERENCE**
>
> N.B. The current implementation saves the values in XML as attributes,
>   so the names must be valid XML names.
>   Versions of JMeter after 2.3.2 send the variable to all servers
>   to ensure that the correct data is available at the client.

If you run JMeter in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as follows:

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=name,DOBZ,SSN -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/testresults.jtl
```

You'll see output like:

> 1419084819822,465,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,1591,1,1,465,**${name} variable value**,**${DOBZ} variable value**, **${SSN} variable value**

Alternatively you can:

- set `sample_variables` property in *user.properties* file
- uncomment `sample_variables` property in *jmeter.properties* file and set it to desired value

For more information on different JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them see [Apache JMeter Properties Customization](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) Guide

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done using Beanshell.

Check the below example to get an idea.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;


f = new FileOutputStream("path of the file.csv", true); 
p = new PrintStream(f); 
p.println(vars.get("DOBZ") + "," + vars.get("SSN")); 
p.close();
f.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and looks like I getting some light! can you please let me know how can i grab this value to a file "label":"File Path","instructions":"","readOnly":true,"value":"file://C:/SAfax/5816963209865.pdf"